# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy intentando filtrar los datos de un solo personaje en la api de Star Wars pero al intentarlo con el siguiente codigo:

```
const { setPersonajes } = UsePersonajes();

  const params = useParams();
  const paramslista = [params];

  const map = paramslista.map((list) => list.namep);

  var nombre = map[0];

  useEffect(() => {
    unicoPersonaje(params.name)
  }, []);

  const filtro = setPersonajes.filter((inFilter) => inFilter.name === nombre);
```

El codigo anterior debe cumplir con la funcion de mostrarme solo los detalles de un personaje pero cuando lo ejecuto no me muestra absolutamente nada y no logro saber como solucionarlo

El codigo del UsePersonaje:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const UsePersonajes = () => {
  const [personajes, setPersonajes] = useState([]);
  const [Contador, setContador] = useState(1);

  const dismin = () => {
    if (Contador <= 1) {
      setContador(1);
    } else {
      setContador(Contador - 1);
    }
  };

  const aumen = () => {
    if (Contador < 9) {
      setContador(Contador + 1);
    } else {
      setContador(9);
    }
  };

  const getAllPersonaje = async(numberPage) => {
    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        redirect: 'follow'
      };
      
      fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=${numberPage}`, 
      requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => setPersonajes(result.results))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  };
  
  return {
    getAllPersonaje,
    personajes,
    Contador,
    aumen,
    dismin
  };
};
```

Al realizar el codigo me aparece este error que me deja la pantalla solo con el fondo predeterminado (no me carga nada):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter'):
```

Aun no entiendo donde esta el error, agradeceria de sus ayudas.

Comment: en el useState en  personajes se muestra información de la api  en la función UsePersonajes

Comment: `setPersonajes` tiene un valor `undefined` a la hora de aplicar `filter`. Revisa con atención esta linea `const { setPersonajes } = UsePersonajes();` tira unos logs y verifica que `setPersonajes` este llegando y que sea un `array`.